# What the error in this snippet of scala code?

Tags: java, arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd

i am a newbie to scala and spark. I get compilation error on intellij for the below statement which is inside the main function:-

```
val userIdBySession = epochByUserId.map(getSessions)
```

Compilation error on intellij:-

```
Type Mismatch, expected:(String, Seq[Long])=> NotInferedU, 
                 actual:(String, Seq[Long])=> (String, Int, Int, Int, Int)
```

My declaration for getSessions method :

```
def getSessions(userId:String, epochList:Seq[Long]):(String, Int, Int, Int, Int)
```

A sample of epochByUserId RDD:

```
(b3a60c78,CompactBuffer(1471330761, 1471330761, 1471330791, 1471330791))
(eaefd399,CompactBuffer(1471330773))
(721f634f,CompactBuffer(1471330820))
```

How to correct this compilation error ? Why am i getting the error : NotInferedU. Also, does compactBuffer type correspond to Seq[Long] as in getSessions definition ?

Comment: What happens is you make the type of `epochList` in `getSessnions` a `CompactBuffer[Long]`? Trying that can help answer your last question.

Comment: @Metropolis, there seems to be no type called CompactBuffer. CompactBuffer is the subclass of Seq